# c# Numbers stored in string to variables conversion

Tags: c#, string, numbers, double, converters

I have a string with 4 numbers

```
 string str ="1234 456 78 4.25847";
```

I need to get 4 variables out of it

int a as 1234
int b as 456
int c as 78
double d as 4.25847

Any suggestions on how to pull the variables? The string always remains the same with 3 integers and 1 double at the end.

Comment: In which part of your code did you get into trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    string numbers = "1234 456 78 4.25847";

    string[] splitedNumbers =  numbers.Split(' ');

    int a = Convert.ToInt32(splitedNumbers[0]);
    int b =Convert.ToInt32(splitedNumbers[1]);
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(splitedNumbers[2]);
    double d = Convert.ToDouble(splitedNumbers[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the original string into an array of strings and then parse each item:

```
string data = "1234 456 78 4.25847";

string[] parts = data.Split(' ');

int a = int.Parse(parts[0]);
int b = int.Parse(parts[1]);
int c = int.Parse(parts[2]);
double d = double.Parse(parts[3], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @AlekDepler - the OP code is working ?

Comment: double d = double.Parse("4.25847"); -> Input string was not in a correct format. Is "double.Parse" locale-dependent? On my system digits delimeter is "," and double.Parse("4,25847"); works fine.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips - check my post

Comment: I've updated my answer, I was going to use "lt-LT" as the culture (the OPs own culture), but I doubt this would work as I think Lithuania uses a comma for the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code (it will not work):

```
var CultureName =
                "ru-RU";
                //"en-US";
            System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfi = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(CultureName, false).NumberFormat;

            var numbers_str = "1234 456 78 4.25847";
            var numbers_array = numbers_str.Split(' ');

            var a = int.Parse(numbers_array[0], nfi);
            var b = int.Parse(numbers_array[1], nfi);
            var c = int.Parse(numbers_array[2], nfi);
            var d = double.Parse(numbers_array[3], nfi);
```

The thing is different cultures have diffrent decimal separator, so this will not work for Russian locale (and some others i think). But after setting NumberFormatInfo manually all works fine.